# error C2228: left of '.Alloc' must have class/struct/union

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a SDK (GigE C++), which defines a class like this:

```
class PV_BUFFER_API PvBuffer
 {

public: 

 PvBuffer();
 virtual ~PvBuffer();
 PvPayloadType GetPayloadType() const;
 #ifndef PV_NODEPRECATED
 PvResult Alloc( PvUInt32 aSizeX, PvUInt32 aSizeY, PvPixelType aPixelType );
};
```

The document of the SDK says:

```
 PvResult PvBuffer::Alloc  ( PvUInt32  aSizeX,  
 PvUInt32  aSizeY,  
 PvPixelType  aPixelType   
 )    

 Allocates memory for this PvBuffer. 

 Parameters:
 [in]  aSizeX  The width of the image, in pixels. See GetWidth.  
 [in]  aSizeY  The height of the image, in pixels. See GetHeight.  
 [in]  aPixelType  The GEV pixel type from which the pixel depth is extracted. For     
 supported pixel types, see PvPixelType.h. 

 Returns:
 Includes:
 PvResult::Code::OK 
 PvResult::Code::NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY
```

I want to use the function Alloc (see the last function in the class). So I am writing like this the program:

```
 PvBuffer *lBuffer;  //Class name is PvBuffer
 PvResult lResult= lBuffer.Alloc( 1224, 1029,  PVPIXELMONO );
```

But it is giving errors, one of those is:

```
error C2228: left of '.Alloc' must have class/struct/union
```

Is  syntax correct? Why it is asking for the class?What is the correct way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
PvBuffer *lBuffer;  //Class name is PvBuffer
PvResult lResult= lBuffer.Alloc( 1224, 1029,  PVPIXELMONO );
```

leaving aside that this invokes **undefined behavior**, as `lBuffer` isn't initialized, you want:

```
PvResult lResult= lBuffer->Alloc( 1224, 1029,  PVPIXELMONO );
```

because `lBuffer` is a pointer.

Comment: Did that and now Intellisense is reporting: Error: No instance of overloaded function "PvBuffer::Alloc"matches the argument list ... is it because my parameter is wrong?

Comment: @gpuguy compile first. Intellisense is not a compiler.

Comment: @gpuguy also, that's a different question entirely. :)

Comment: @gpuguy please post a new question, don't enlarge a question when it was already answered.

Answer (score 1):

`lBuffer` is `PvBuffer*`, you need create and deference:

```
lBuffer = new PvBuffer()
lBuffer->Alloc(....);
```